# How can I automatically push data to my website and re-render it accordingly?

Tags: python, html, web, backend, screen-scraping

I currently have a python script that grabs the title and thumbnail of the latest news article on a website called Deca.com. These pieces of information are simply saved as an image and a line of text. I want to know if there is a simple way for me to run this script on some type of scheduler (every day) and then import the resulting data into my current website, which would re-render the UI to display any changes to the latest article on Deca.com. I have no experience with back-end web development, so I'm not exactly sure what this would require. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are running Linux, a crontab is probably easiest. Just put the files into whatever directory your webserver is fetching the static files from.

Comment: You might try using AJAX along with Socket.io.  Python has a package for that:  https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.  Set a timer for your socket, then make the AJAX call to fetch the latest content, and the socket pushes it to your site.  There could be other options, but this is what came to mind.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach is to save either the data itself (text) or instructions-to-find-the-data (eg. path to stored jpg file) in a MySQL/MariaDB database, and then populate the news-feed section of your website from the database.

On page load, you would make an ajax call to the database, receive back the data from MySQL, and then loop through the received rows of data (each row will be one news article) to construct your news feed.

You will need Flask, of course, and then there are several libraries to choose from that will let you read/write to the MySQL database, such as: sqlalchemy/pymysql, or MySQLdb, or MySQL Connector Python, or...

You will need to use `pip install`*`[library name]`* to install your chosen python libraries before you can use them, both on your server and also in your local development environment. If you haven't yet chosen a dev environment, I heartily recommend VSCode (with Python extension installed) as the IDE together with XAMPP as the local server-with-MySQL. *(Note that the freeware version of MySQL has recently forked and been rebranded as MariaDB)*

You should be able to find countless tutorials online that will teach you how to do this, but here are a few that all deal with the MySQLdb library:

https://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/python-read-data-from-mysql-database/

https://www.webtrainingroom.com/python/python-mysql-fetch-example

https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2017/09/09/using-python-to-read-data-from-a-mysql-database/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpQw4Q7n0_g